# Why does my "Create Table" statement return "Near '(': syntax error"?

Tags: sql, typescript, sqlite, node-sqlite3

Error :

> Near "(": syntax error

SQL statement :

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tickets (
    numero INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    identifier VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    subject VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    concerned_staff TEXT NULL,
    author_id VARCHAR(22) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    is_archived BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    ticket_channel_id VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL
);
```

I do not understand why. [The only other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341525/sqlite-create-table-near-syntax-error) doesn't fit what I'm doing. My goal is to get a numeric value of the time. I don't want `21-12-2022 10:00:00` but `1671613200`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not understand why.

Change `current_timestamp()` to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

> I don't want `21-12-2022 10:00:00` but `1671613200`.

`created_at TIMESTAMP` resolves to numeric [affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) while `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns string value. Use [`unixepoch()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) instead:

```
created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT (unixepoch()),
```